# Android Theme.AppCompat.Light with Dark Toolbar (for light text)

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have an app using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` which I need to use so Dialogs have the light theme. But this makes the text in my toolbar black, where I'd rather it be white. I've tried setting the toolbar's specific `app:theme` to `AppCompat.Dark.Actionbar`, but no luck... I searched around for a while and couldn't find a specific question and answer to this.

Here's my default **AppTheme**:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Parent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/pink</item>

    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Here's my **toolbar.xml**:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Have you try to set the `style` attribute on your toolbar?

Comment: @Gaëtan just tried it, and same issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to change the color of the title in your `Toolbar` you simply have to add the attribute `android:textColorPrimary` to your *Toolbar style*.

Please see the following example for even more attributes of the Toolbar.

#### Example

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar when parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the text of the action menu icons -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the overflow menu icon -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    <!-- Color of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:background">#455a64</item>
</style>
```

#### Result

[image: picture of the result]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do anything for me :s. Out of curiosity, what's your min SDK version?

Comment: 14 but this shouldn't matter at all. Did you set the style properly in the `app:theme`?

Comment: I tried again and it worked... I think the issue with your code was the parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar". I used "parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" and got the results instead. Marking yours as right as it had the right code essentially (setting textColorPrimary in a dedicated Toolbar style). Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear. Actually the parent stuff is optional afaik.

Comment: interesting... not sure what it is/was then. The new Toolbar code is pretty wonky still, it seems.

Comment: On a related note: from my experience with `AppCompat`, you should still define the `background` in the Toolbar's xml and not on the Toolbar style you apply with `app:theme` (in this case, `MyToolbarStyle`) or the color will be propagated to the overflow menu, even if you set a `app:popupTheme`, which might be inappropriate in many cases.

Comment: The menu background is white and the menu text color is white = box of white

Comment: setting the "android:background" in the style to the primary color, did fix it the menu background color to not be white. (I was previously setting the toolbar background in the layout xml and I got a white option menu background)

Answer (score 2):

You can customize toolbar yourself no need to set default text, use your own textview :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

   <!-- Below will add your text in the center of toolbar -->
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Your Text"
        android:textColor=#ff0000
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: There's no need to add an additional `TextView` to the `Toolbar` in order to change the color of the title. `android:textColorPrimary` does this already - see my answer as well.

Comment: There is no option called android:textColorPrimary for android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. (At least for API 16)

Comment: @elf_zwölf Not for the Toolbar itself but for the `Style` which you can apply to the `Toolbar`

Answer (score 0):

While custom styling may work, the AppCompat library already provides an easy way to do this. If your `Toolbar`'s background color is dark/doesn't provide enough contrast, use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark as its parent:

`<style name="MyTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />`

Then style your `Toolbar accordingly:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/some_dark_color"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

`Toolbar`s using backgrounds with lighter colors should use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light` as their parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this work in 2021, the first set of themes in the activity android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" and set theme in xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```