# Change color on back button (on ActionBar)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How to change back button color in `ActionBar`? (From black to white color).
It's screenshot with this button:

[image]

And how to change spinner arrow color on `ActionBar`?

Comment: change the drawable used in the toolbar!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following works for me with `ToolBar`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
   <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDrawerArrowToggle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
  <item name="color">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

### EDIT

---

#### Option 2

```
<style name="ToolbarThemeWhite" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

set this style to toolbar

Comment: and how to change spinner arrow color? (Your answer is correct!)

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551230/android-theme-appcompat-light-with-dark-toolbar-for-light-text

Comment: this isn't changing anything on android 5 and 6 devices. Can you please check?

Answer (score 2):

following code sample worked for me

```
 <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <!--below line used to change the color of home(back) button color-->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try to this :

[image]
[image: !Change Menu color in Navigation]

### In style.xml :

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>


</style>

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

### In Mainfests.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base"></activity>
```