# Android Light AppTheme with Dark ActionBar (AppCompat)

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-toolbar, android-styles

I have Application Theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` which gives light theme to my App, so texts on `Dialogs` etc are dark. I want also my `Toolbar` have dark background and light foreground, so i write these to `Toolbar`:

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

**Problem:** This makes `Toolbar` dark and texts, back icon white on Lollipop, but does NOT work on KitKat:

**Lollipop:**

[image]

---

**KitKat**:
[image]

**Question:** How to make Dark Toolbar with Light content on KitKat with my current theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` ?

Comment: Are you using styles.xml v21?

Comment: @4k3R no, just styles.xml

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? I am currently fighting the same issue with no success.

Comment: @shelll i dont remember, try using `android:theme` and `app:popupTheme`

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov I tried `android:theme` and `app:theme` and none of them wrok. The `app:popupTheme` works for the popup menu. Just the title and icons have wrong color.

Comment: The issue was I was calling `super.onCreate(...)` after `setContentView(...)` in my `Activity`. This is a special need for a 3rd party library :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to for the title of the Toolbar when parent is Theme.AppCompat.Light -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the text of the action menu icons -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>
    <!-- Used to color the overflow menu icon -->
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    <!-- Color of the Toolbar -->
    <item name="android:background">#455a64</item>
</style>
```

Check out this post:

> [Android Theme.AppCompat.Light with Dark Toolbar (for light text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551230/android-theme-appcompat-light-with-dark-toolbar-for-light-text)

Comment: yeah i've read this before, this is for changing just text color, which didn't work for me don't know why) My aim is to change back icon color as well